# delete groups with more than 2 missing value

Tags: r

As you can see, it is a panel data, all observations are grouped by the variable PERMCO, I need to delete all groups that have more than 2 missing values in the variable vwretd or that have missing value in the variable PRC or SHROUT in date 1935-06-30. I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: I think `subset` from `base R` can do this.

Comment: @user2100721's suggestion is probably good enough. If you want more assistance, please (1) include data that meets your criterion, and (2) provide it in a way that is easily tested by us volunteers. For instance, it is not obvious that all obs are grouped by `PERMCO`, as that field is constant. I suggest you provide a varied and smaller dataset that sufficiently demonstrates the conditions under which your criteria will be usable. (Hint: it doesn't need to be actual data, fake works as well if you can learn the code to do what you need.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the dataset seems to be `data.table`, we can do this with `data.table` methods.  Grouped by 'PERMCO', `if` the negation (`!`) of the number of NA elements (`sum(is.na(vwretd))`) is greater than 2, or (`|`) `all` the 'PRC' (or 'SHROUT') elements that corresponds to the '1935-06-30' 'date' is `NA`, is TRUE for a particular group, we get the Subset of Data.table.

```
library(data.table)
dt[, if( !(sum(is.na(vwretd)) >2| all(is.na(PRC[date == "1935-06-30"])) | 
              all(is.na(SHROUT[date == "1935-06-30"]))) .SD , by = PERMCO]
```

Comment: Will this command delete the whole observations within a group that meet the deleting criteria?

Comment: @YifanLiu  It should delete it (though haven't tested it completely as your example didn't had any missing values)

Comment: may i ask what does the ".SD" mean? by the way, how can I only keep those groups that have exactly 120 observations?

Comment: I used your command and adapted it a little bit, but it did not work. My command is as below 'Data.1936.clean<-Data.1936.full[,if(!(sum(is.na(Data.1936.full$stkr)) >2|
                                       all(is.na(Data.1936.full$mktcap[date == "1935-06-30"])))) .SD, 
                                       by = PERMNO]'

Comment: @YifanLiu `.SD` means subset of data.table.  If  you want to keep only 120 observations (assuming that all groups have > 120 observations, `head(.SD, 120)` in pace of .SD.  Regarding your second comment `it did not work` did not give much info regarding what is not working.